# Add a highlight to a single section of a ggplot chart while maintaining sort

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a chart, with a 'ribbon' behind the chart highlighting a specific client.  However, if I try to add the ribbon, the sorting I've put together disappears and it reverts.  Here's an example:

Sorted correctly, but no ribbon:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  mutate(Brand = word(Car, 1,1, sep = " ")) %>%
  mutate(Brand = ifelse(Brand %in% c('Fiat','Toyota','Hornet', 'Merc'), Brand, 'zOther')) %>%
  mutate(focus = ifelse(Brand == 'Toyota', Brand, NA_character_)) %>%
  mutate(Brand=reorder(Brand, mpg, mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Brand, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  NULL
```

[image]

Ribbon added, but losing sort:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  mutate(Brand = word(Car, 1,1, sep = " ")) %>%
  mutate(Brand = ifelse(Brand %in% c('Fiat','Toyota','Hornet', 'Merc'), Brand, 'zOther')) %>%
  mutate(focus = ifelse(Brand == 'Toyota', Brand, NA_character_)) %>%
  mutate(Brand=reorder(Brand, mpg, mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Brand, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(aes(x=focus,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf), colour="grey", size=23, alpha=0.3) + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  NULL
```

[image]

I have successfully done this in the past, but nothing seems to be co-operating today.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`geom_linerange()` is not the right function for your purpose.

A better option in my opinion is using `annotate(geom = "rect", ...)`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Brand, y = mpg)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3.5, xmax = 4.5, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "lightgrey", alpha=0.6) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  NULL
```

[image]

**EDIT**: To pass the ribbon in as a variable do:

```
mtcars %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  mutate(Brand = word(Car, 1,1, sep = " ")) %>%
  mutate(Brand = ifelse(Brand %in% c('Fiat','Toyota','Hornet', 'Merc'), Brand, 'zOther')) %>%
  mutate(focus = ifelse(Brand == 'Toyota', 0.6, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Brand=reorder(Brand, mpg, mean)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Brand, y = mpg)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x=Brand,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf, alpha=I(focus)), colour="grey", size=23) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  NULL
```

Your `focus`-variable now contains the alpha value. 0.6 for Toyota and 0 for everyone else. Inside the `aes()` statement of `geom_linerange()` we assign `focus` to the `alpha=` aesthetic "as is", meaning taking our values `0.6`and `0`.

Comment: The focus client can change, though - is there some way to pass the name in as a variable, rather than "3.5 to 4.5"?  I don't know what position it will be sitting at...